# window.history.pushState() does not work on URLSearchParams

Tags: javascript, reactjs, urlsearchparams

Hi I am trying to pass params to backend from frontend using URLSearchParams to filter a list.
The filtering did not happen without reloading the page because URLSearchParams wasn't updated.
I wrote code as follows by searching the answers on this website but it still doesn't update.
Please tell me what is wrong.

**HomeScreens.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import Filterbar from '../components/Filterbar';
// import PhotosnapIcon from '~/images/photosnap.svg';
import { listJobs } from '../actions/jobActions';

import './HomeScreen.scss';

export default function HomeScreen() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const jobList = useSelector((state) => state.jobList);
  const { loading, error, jobs } = jobList;

  let [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

  const params = [];

  searchParams.forEach((value, key) => {
    params.push([key, value]);
  });

  const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(params);

  const url = new URL(window.location.href);
  window.history.pushState(null, null, url);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listJobs(queryParams));
    console.log(jobs);
  }, [dispatch]);

  const addQuery = (key, value) => {
    setSearchParams((prev) => [...prev.entries(), [key, value]]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Filterbar />
      <ul>
        {jobs.map((job) => (
          <li className={job.featured ? 'post featured' : 'post'} key={job._id}>
            <div className="post__img-container">
              <img src={job.logo} alt="photosnap" />
            </div>
            <div className="post__upper-container">
              <div className="post__company-container">
                <h2 className="post__company">{job.company}</h2>
                {job.new && <span className="post__label new">new!</span>}
                {job.featured && (
                  <span className="post__label featured">featured</span>
                )}
              </div>
              <h3 className="post__job-title">{job.position}</h3>
              <div className="post__data">
                <span className="post__date">{job.postedAt}</span>
                <div className="post__dot"></div>
                <span className="post__hours">{job.contract}</span>
                <div className="post__dot"></div>
                <span className="post__location">{job.location}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="post__lower-container">
              <button
                className="post__category"
                name="role"
                value={job.role}
                onClick={(e) => addQuery('role', e.currentTarget.value)}
              >
                <span>{job.role}</span>
              </button>{' '}
              <button
                className="post__category"
                value={job.level}
                onClick={(e) => addQuery('level', e.currentTarget.value)}
              >
                <span>{job.level}</span>
              </button>
              {job.languages.map((language) => (
                <button
                  className="post__category"
                  name="language"
                  value={language}
                  onClick={(e) => addQuery('languages', e.currentTarget.value)}
                >
                  <span>{language}</span>
                </button>
              ))}
              {job.tools.map((tool) => (
                <button
                  className="post__category"
                  name="tool"
                  value={tool}
                  onClick={(e) => addQuery('tools', e.currentTarget.value)}
                >
                  <span>{tool}</span>
                </button>
              ))}
            </div>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}
```

**jobActions.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

import {
  JOB_LIST_REQUEST,
  JOB_LIST_SUCCESS,
  JOB_LIST_FAIL,
} from '../constants/jobConstants';

export const listJobs = (queryParams) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: JOB_LIST_REQUEST });

    console.log(queryParams);

    const { data } = await axios.get('/api/jobs', { params: queryParams });

    dispatch({
      type: JOB_LIST_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: JOB_LIST_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

**backend>controller>jobs.js**

```
import ErrorResponse from '../utils/errorResponse.js';
import asyncHandler from '../middleware/async.js';
import Job from '../models/Job.js';

// @desc Get all jobs
// @routes GET /api/jobs
// @access Public
const getJobs = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  // let query;

  // copy req.query
  const reqQuery = { ...req.query };

  // create query string
  let queryStr = JSON.stringify(reqQuery);

  // create operators ($gt, $gte, etc)
  queryStr = queryStr.replace(
    /\b(gt|gte|lt|lte|in)\b/g,
    (match) => `$${match}`
  );

  // Finding resource
  const jobs = await Job.find(JSON.parse(queryStr));

  console.log(jobs);
 
  res.json(jobs);


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to add `searchParams` in dependency array in useEffect to re-render whenever serchParams is changed. When I put `queryParams` in the dep array I got indefinate loop, so I was confused, but `searchParams` is working.

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listJobs(queryParams));
  }, [dispatch, searchParams]);
```